# targeting mysqli assoc array indivdual values easily

Tags: php, mysqli

How should I be doing this? $id1 returns the first character of the value, I also tried $id1 = $row[0]['id']; but that didn't seem to return anything.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,postid FROM table WHERE postid='$postid' LIMIT 3";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$id1 = $row['id'][0];
$postid1 = $row['postidx'][0];
$id2 = $row['id'][1];
$postid2 = $row['postid'][1];
$id2 = $row['id'][2];
$postid2 = $row['postid'][2];
}
```

Comment: instead of doing with this much variable. create one variable outside of the loop as an array variable and inside loop `$newly_created_array_variable[] = $row;`

Comment: `$id1 = $row['id'][0];` should be `$id1 = $row['id'];` ... debug `$row` with print_r

Comment: $id1 = $row['id']; just gives all the values, does it?

Comment: put `echo "id: ".$row['id']." - postid: ".$row['postidx']."<br>";` to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the concept of *loops*.
Your code works not the way you think. You will get your subsequent rows as the loop iterates. So you need to get only current row values within the loop, and use them accordingly

```
$sql = "SELECT id,postid FROM table WHERE postid='$postid' LIMIT 3";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $postid = $row['postid'];
    // use these two variables
}
```

Comment: Your comment is useful in that I do need to understand loops and arrays better.